# How did Dizzi get trapped in Kenny's laptop?

Tags: beyblade

In the English dub of *Beyblade: Classic*, Kenny has a bit-beast named Dizzy trapped inside his laptop. It's implied that it’s Kenny’s fault that Dizzy got trapped.

Is it ever explained how Dizzy got trapped inside Kenny’s laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kenny said that one day when he plugged his laptop, there was a massive power surge and Dizzi popped up in Kenny's Computer.

The reason for the same is clearly mentioned in the **Second Episode of Season one**, titled, *"Day of the Dragoon"*. 
After Tyson loses to Kai, Andrew and Kenny go to Tyson's house to check on him.  Here, Kenny tells Tyson who Dizzi was and goes on to mention the above stated reason.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the entry about Dizzi on beyblade.org](https://www.beyblade.org/beyblade-bit-beasts-part-1/):

> Dizzi was accidentally trapped inside Kenny's laptop due to a
>   lightning storm that caused her to transfer her body to it.

I have read this answer also on other websites, but I haven't found a reference to the manga or anime. So, I don't know, where it has been explained.